# How to get the iterator value in another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jpa, struts2

I have 2 class one is question and another one is answer.iam getting questions in a list in action class and in my jsp page iam using iterator and display the questions in questions page.All questions have the href.when i click on first quesion i want to get the question in answer page.
here my code is there,
 This is my question action class execute method

```
     PersistenceService service1 = PersistenceServiceImpl.getInstance();
     questionlist = service1.getQuestionList();
     Iterator iterator1 = questionlist.iterator();
      while(iterator1.hasNext())
      {
      Questions question = (Questions)iterator1.next();
                                  System.out.println("id1"+question.getQuestions());

                     }
```

here iam getting all questions

my question jsp page is

```
 <s:iterator value="questionList" var="m" status="status">
  <tr>          
   <td><a href="AnswerAction"><s:property value="%{#m.questions}" /></a></td>
   </tr>                
   </s:iterator>
```

Please tell me how to get the on click question in answer page

Answer (score 0):

You getting  questionlist  list,then why your Iterating movieNameList.if question are availble in movieNameList,your need to iterate

```
   <s:iterator value="movieNameList" status="movieNameList_status">
 <tr>          
     <td><a href="AnswerAction"><s:property value="movieNameList.get(#movieNameList_status.index).question.getQuestions()"/> </a></td>
  </tr>                
  </s:iterator>
```

try this,,